# How would I go about incrementing an integer in C when the user opens a program?

Tags: c, game-development

I'm currently writing a text-based adventure game and I have a lifetime counter. I wanted to know if it would be possible to increment the lifetime counter upon starting the game without using a file?

I am using Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Dunno.  What non-volatile storage does your system have?

Comment: Your question don't mention your OS and does not show any [mre]

Comment: I have added my OS to the question. Please reopen it.

Answer (score 4):

**This is operating system specific**, since while the C11 draft standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) does mention files (in section §7.21) it does not mention other ways of [persisting data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)).

You might consider using some [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database), e.g. the [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) library or [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/) or [MongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB). It might be overkill.

You could consider keeping persistent data (like suggested in [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report, or coded in C++ in the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) software) in some textual format such as [JSON](http://json.org/). Concepts and terminology from [garbage collection](https://gchandbook.org/) could be relevant (e.g. [Cheney's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheney%27s_algorithm)). Read at least the old [*Uniprocessor Garbage Collection Techniques*](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Paul_Wilson34/publication/225216046_Uniprocessor_Garbage_Collection_Techniques/links/5570624c08aee1eea7586fcb.pdf) paper for terminology.

You might be interested by [web services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service), using [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) and/or [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) and/or [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt). Before that, read documentation related to [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). You might consider using [JSONRPC](https://www.jsonrpc.org/) or [SWIG](http://swig.org/).

On Linux you might consider using shared memory or other ways of [interprocess communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) with several cooperating [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)), see [shm_overview(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html), [sem_overview(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html), [fifo(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), [unix(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html), [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) and other [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (and [atexit(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html)). Read then [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

On Windows you need to read the [documentation of the WinAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/).

You could be interested by the [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standard and by cross-platform libraries like [GTK](https://gtk.org/) or [libSDL](https://www.libsdl.org/). Both are often used in game software.

Notice that [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) has some persistence machinery (see also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_Bank_Common_Lisp)). You might take inspiration from its [`save-lisp-and-die` primitive](http://sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Saving-a-Core-Image). You could also write parts of your game in [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/) and take advantage of Ocaml's [`Marshal` module](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Stdlib.Marshal.html). You could [embed Python](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) (or [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), or [Lua](https://lua.org/)) in your game software and use its [persistence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html) features. Even if you don't code in SBCL or Ocaml, you could take inspiration from their runtime C code.

> I'm currently writing a text-based adventure game and I have a lifetime counter.

Then look also (for inspiration) inside the source code of *existing* games on [github](https://github.com/).

Comment: Hi Basile, your SBCL link is dead, is this primitive something similar to the bash environment variables?

Comment: For me, near Paris, in France, that SBCL link works. And you might also Google it. I don't understand your comment about [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) which is *not* relevant to the OP's question

Comment: Sorry, I mean this save-lisp-and-die primitive, is an environment variable what you are saving? I can't understand the mechanism

Comment: Oh, it is not necessary, thank you, I have already found the information about save-lisp-and-die, very interesting!